# In this method [e.getButton] where this object e came from?

Tags: java

I know that in order to use objects or instances you have to initialize it first, e.g. `A a = new A ()`, then why does that object `e` in the line `e.getButton()` work without initializing it?

```java
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
        System.out.println("Left button clicked!");
    else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        System.out.println("Right button clicked!");
}
```

I know `e` is parameter of `mouseClicked` method, but to use it must initialize it first, and in the code above is not initialized. Why?

Comment: It's being initialized somewhere else before it is passed as an argument to `mouseClicked`

Comment: See the `MouseEvent e` in the method declaration? That is where it is coming form. It contains the value passed by the caller, so it is already initialized when the method is run.

Comment: Because it's receiving an instance, not the class.

Comment: This is actually a good question from a beginner. For better understanding try with breakpoints in IDE and you can see the caller function (internal to JDK) and how it is initialized

Comment: You wrote: _I know `e` is parameter of `mouseClicked` method, but to use it must initialize it first_ No. You don't need to initialize it first in order to use it. This is because it is a method parameter. You only need to initialize variables that you declare and a method parameter is **not** a variable that you declare.

Answer (score 1):

The `MouseEvent` `e` is a parameter of the method.  The caller provides the argument to this parameter so you are NOT responsible for creating the instance.

You appear to be implementing a `MouseListener`.  That listener will be registered with some component.  When the program is executed and the user manipulates their mouse, a `MouseEvent` will be fired.  The framework will find that your listener is registered to handle that event and will pass the event to the method.