# Where that instance (e) in this method mouseclicked(MouseListener e) initialized?

Tags: javascript, java, events, methods, mouselistener

in the method mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) can anyone explain to me where that instance (e) initialized  ?

```
@Override
```

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

```
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)

        System.out.println("Left button clicked!");

    else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)

        System.out.println("Right button clicked!");

}
```

Is the System initialized ? And where ?

Comment: You've already posted this exact same question and basically got your answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983578/in-this-method-e-getbutton-where-this-object-e-came-from#comment134013692_75983578

Comment: I did not understand the answers well, although I read it many times , but I understood the answer of the master Unimitigated , thank you all friends 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In this method \[e.getButton\] where this object e came from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983578/in-this-method-e-getbutton-where-this-object-e-came-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you register a `MouseListener` on a component by calling `addMouseListener`, that component will call the appropriate method on each `MouseListener` attached to it whenever a `MouseEvent` occurs, passing the `MouseEvent` as the first argument.

See also the [`MouseListener` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html):

> The class that is interested in processing a mouse event either implements this interface (and all the methods it contains) or extends the abstract MouseAdapter class (overriding only the methods of interest). 
> The listener object created from that class is then registered with a component using the component's addMouseListener method. A mouse event is generated when the mouse is pressed, released clicked (pressed and released). A mouse event is also generated when the mouse cursor enters or leaves a component. When a mouse event occurs, the relevant method in the listener object is invoked, and the MouseEvent is passed to it.

Comment: Thank you so much  , i was asking why some methods must initialize the objects that in parameters of that methods and some methods non , what i understood from your answer that there's some methods you have to initialize the object (parameter) by yourself and some the system do it for you like this method, thank you